# Email field Validator in sapui5

Tags: regex, sapui5

I am trying to validate email and phone number is sapui5. i have done with RegEx. but i want to know sapui5 having any inbuild eMail and Phone number field validator? Without using RegEx?

Answer (score 3):

Update:

Same for sap.ui and sap.m, as the following solution is achieved by data binding validation.

there is no built-in eMail and Phone number field validator. You need to build your own sap.ui.model.SimpleType. Please see the example for [Email validation](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputChecked/preview):

Answer (score 0):

here is an example of validation function, attached to event "liveChange" and changing property "ValueState" for sap.m.Input field:

http://jsbin.com/gedap/1/edit?html,css,js,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" id="sap-ui-bootstrap" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script>
  var input = new sap.m.Input({ 
              liveChange : function(oEvent){
                var value = parseInt(oEvent.getSource().getProperty('value'));
                var valueState = isNaN(value) ? "Error" : value > 3 ? "Error" : "Success";
                oEvent.getSource().setValueState(valueState);
              }});
  input.placeAt('content');  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='content'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

If this is field you are planning to use, then it is easy and fast :)